# Mobile sub menus different in chrome/ff

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having trouble figuring out why my mobile sub menu is behaving differently in Chrome and Firefox. Take a look at http://weebowebdev.com/ in any resolution below 1200px. Click on the menu toggle to open up the menu, mouse over the Property Search link to see the sub menu.

You will notice in Firefox that the menu behaves exactly how I want it do. In Chrome, however, you will notice the sub menu is stuck inside the primary menu container. I need to figure out how to fix the sub menu in Chrome so it behaves exactly the same as it does in Firefox. Any help is appreciated.

The css is as follows:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 0.45s ease 0s;
  text-align: left;
  width: 185px;
  left: -999em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.45s ease;
  transition: all 0.45s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    margin-top:32px;
    position:absolute;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.menu-top-menu-container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.menu-top-menu-container`

or Add CSS for this

```
.menu-top-menu-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **margin-left:-25px** below 1200px resolution from submenu.

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 99999;
    transition: all 0.45s ease 0s;
    text-align: left;
    width: 185px;
    left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
}
```

**Add This css**

```
@media (max-width:1200px){
    .main-navigation ul ul { margin-left:0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anybody don't see your case, you must ask a question not assign your work to experts in `StackOverFlow`. but I saw your website, your CSS codes are pretty dark dirty. you use a negative margin for your menu layout!! it's not a good way. you must clean your CSS codes and then use `position: relative;` for your second `ul`. I recommend using overlay design for the menu in Mobile. a drop-down menu is not very formal in Mobile design. using a large negative value for left or right is not rational.

You can use the styles of `Bootstrap` or `UIKit` or `Semantic UI` for your menu in Mobile.